# Bug in package pdfrender?

Tags: tables

In trying to understand what the parameters in pdfrender do, I just made a table to study the effect. I noticed that when I use one of the *clip* modes (4-7) the following second table disappears completely after the `\hline`.
Without the `\hline` the table appears normally.
Is this a bug or a feature?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfrender}
\begin{document}
\kvsetkeys{PDFRENDER}{LineWidth=0.1pt}
\begin{tabular}{ccll}
Mode & LW & Normal & Rendered \\\hline
4 & 0.1 & Text & \textpdfrender {TextRenderingMode=4}{Text} \\
\end{tabular}

\kvsetkeys{PDFRENDER}{LineWidth=0.4pt
\begin{tabular}{ccll}
Mode & LW & Normal & Rendered \\\hline
0 & 0.1 & Text & \textpdfrender {TextRenderingMode=0}{Text} \\
1 & 0.1 & Text & \textpdfrender {TextRenderingMode=1}{Text} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug. The code is wrong here, according to the pdf reference the BT operator must be closed before the mode is switched back, and it looks as if one also should save and restore the graphic state.

But I don't see at first glance an easy fix. You could open an issue at the github.

Manually something like this works. But better don't use this mode in text which can contain a page break. I added the red rule only to demonstrate that the clipping works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color,pdfrender}
\begin{document}
\kvsetkeys{PDFRENDER}{LineWidth=0.1pt}
\begin{tabular}{ccll}
Mode & LW & Normal & Rendered \\\hline
4 & 0.1 & Text & \pdfliteral page {q}\textpdfrender {TextRenderingMode=4}{Text\llap{\textcolor{red}{\rule{3cm}{0.4cm}}}\pdfliteral page {Q}} \\
\end{tabular}

\kvsetkeys{PDFRENDER}{LineWidth=0.4pt}
\begin{tabular}{ccll}
Mode & LW & Normal & Rendered \\\hline
0 & 0.1 & Text & \textpdfrender {TextRenderingMode=0}{Text} \\
1 & 0.1 & Text & \textpdfrender {TextRenderingMode=1}{Text} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ulrike. I was using \pdfliteral before but switched to pdfrender, because of the page break.
I then wanted to see the effect of (especially) LineWidth, so I created a table and then run in this bug.
I do not need clipping, but I thought I should report this somewhere.

Comment: I have another question though, that you might be able to answer: I am trying to increase the weight of a font that comes only in one weight. I had expected that increasing the LineWith gradually would also increase the weight gradually. But this is not the case. Can you advise me in this matter?

Comment: If you have new question, please ask a new question. Don't do this in comments as it pings only me. Btw: the literal is here not to trigger the rendering effect, only to "sandbox" it.

Comment: You're right, Ulrike. I would do that now, but I figured it out myself already. Thanks again.

Comment: About increasing of weight (which was raised in the comments): The xfakebold package, https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xfakebold, could be used or its code inspected for inspiration. [While Jack figured out how to solve the increasing of weight, Jack did not tell how to do so, thus I thought this comment might help other, future readers.]